# Delphi generate random date time value between range of date time

Tags: delphi, pascal

I am trying to **generate random Tdatetime values** in given range in **delphi 5**
*lets say we have two dates in the follow format*

```
date1=01/01/2018 12:35:32 
date2=05/01/2018 21:35:32
```

i want to generate exaclty "x" dates increased between this range.
As an example i would like to generate 7 Dates from range date1->date2

```
randomdate[0]:=01/01/2018 12:35:32 
randomdate[1]:=01/01/2018 14:35:12 
randomdate[2]:=01/01/2018 16:42:22 
randomdate[3]:=02/01/2018 21:12:01
randomdate[4]:=03/01/2018 11:13:12
randomdate[5]:=04/01/2018 22:20:05
randomdate[6]:=05/01/2018 20:30:05
```

the problem is that if second random date rich the date2 then all other dates must be the same as date2 but if the time gets 23:59:59 next date will be out of range

like the folow senario

```
randomdate[0]:=01/01/2018 12:35:32 
randomdate[1]:=05/01/2018 23:59:59
.................................
```

!! all dates from now on will be

06/01/2018 23:59:59

which is out of my range !!

any help will be appreciate it

After Andreas Suggestion here is the finally code who works on D5 so i guess works on all other versions of delphi

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  StdCtrls, ComCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    RichEdit1: TRichEdit;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

function SecondsBetween(const Time1, Time2: TDateTime): Longint;
const SecsPerMin=60;
const MinsPerHour=60;
const HoursPerDay=24;
begin
result := Round(SecsPerMin * MinsPerHour * HoursPerDay * Abs(Time2 - Time1));
end;


function RandomDateTime( AFrom, ATo: TDateTime): TDateTime;
var
  SecsBetween: int64;
begin
  SecsBetween := SecondsBetween(AFrom,ATo);
  result := AFrom + (Round(SecsBetween * Random) / (60*60*24));
end;


function CreateSortedListOfRandomDatetimes( AFrom, ATo: TDateTime; N: integer): TStringlist;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  result := Tstringlist.Create;
  try
//    result.Capacity := N; // for an unnoticeable increase in performance
    for i := 1 to N do   result.Add(formatdatetime('dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss',RandomDateTime(AFrom, ATo)));
    result.Sort;
  except
    result.Free;
    raise;
  end;
end;


//edit1 Holds the 1st date which is  04/09/2018 16:00:00
//edit2 hold the 2nd date
//edit3 holds the N count value
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  timestamps: Tstringlist;
  i: Integer;
  d1:Tdatetime;
  d2:Tdatetime;
begin
d1:=StrtoDatetime(edit1.text);
d2:=StrtoDatetime(edit2.text);

  timestamps := CreateSortedListOfRandomDatetimes(d1,d2 ,strtoInt(edit3.text));
  try
    RichEdit1.Lines.BeginUpdate;
    try
      RichEdit1.Lines.Clear;
      for i := 0 to timestamps.Count - 1 do
        RichEdit1.Lines.Add(timestamps.strings[i])
    finally
      RichEdit1.Lines.EndUpdate;
    end;
  finally
    timestamps.Free;
  end;

end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
randomize;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Are all milliseconds 0? Do you allow duplicates in the list? Must the list start with `date1`? Must it end with `date2`?

Comment: This seems a fairly trivial problem. I think that you need to show us your [MCVE] code, not just the results.

Comment: No Duplicates ( i prefer the time ranges to have a diff of at least 5 minutes between them.
1st date must be the First date in range
last date must be the last date in range

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A function to generate a random `TDateTime` value between two fixed values can be written like this (`uses DateUtils`):

```
function RandomDateTime(const AFrom, ATo: TDateTime): TDateTime;
var
  SecsBetween: Int64;
begin
  SecsBetween := SecondsBetween(AFrom, ATo);
  result := IncSecond(AFrom, Round(SecsBetween * Random));
end;
```

To create a sorted list of these, use your favourite sorting method. In modern Delphi, you could use the built-in generic list:

```
function CreateSortedListOfRandomDatetimes(const AFrom, ATo: TDateTime; N: integer): TList<TDateTime>;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  result := TList<TDateTime>.Create;
  try
    result.Capacity := N; // for an unnoticeable increase in performance
    for i := 1 to N do
      result.Add(RandomDateTime(AFrom, ATo));
    result.Sort;
  except
    result.Free;
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

Try it out:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  timestamps: TList<TDateTime>;
  i: Integer;
begin
  timestamps := CreateSortedListOfRandomDatetimes(
    EncodeDateTime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    EncodeDateTime(2000, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999),
    10
  );
  try
    RichEdit1.Lines.BeginUpdate;
    try
      RichEdit1.Lines.Clear;
      for i := 0 to timestamps.Count - 1 do
        RichEdit1.Lines.Add(DateTimeToStr(timestamps[i]))
    finally
      RichEdit1.Lines.EndUpdate;
    end;
  finally
    timestamps.Free;
  end;
end;
```

(This approach may produce duplicate datetimes. The Q didn't explicitly mention if this is allowed or not. Also, it only works at second precision, not millisecond precision. You may want to change that, or at least remove the millisecond from `AFrom`.)

Comment: yeap in my delphi 5 i dont have SecondsBetween function i am going write it now.
also i dont understand what IncSecond function does.

Comment: I put as dates 04/09/2018 and 07/09/2018 ( format dd/mm/yyyy) and i ask 10 random dates in range i took.
01/10/2018 04:58:24
05/10/2018 04:48:24
05/11/2018 12:44:48
07/11/2018 21:48:24
08/10/2018 04:58:48
09/10/2018 10:16:24
10/11/2018 23:42:24
11/09/2018 10:52:48
12/11/2018 05:26:48
15/09/2018 13:52:00
seems doesn get the first date

Comment: @delphifive Isn't it quite clear that you made a mistake. In your own functions you use `SecsPerMin * MinsPerHour * HoursPerDay` to convert to seconds but only `/60/60` to convert back.

Comment: Thanks !!!!!!!  Corected  
 result := AFrom + (Round(SecsBetween * Random) / (60*60*24));

Comment: @delphifive: You need to look up how to convert strings to datetimes in Delphi. Use Google.

Comment: Everything works fine now i edited the corect Code. Thanks a lot you save my day today.